# Which ibeacon used for alerting mobile application from wallet(smart wallet)?

Tags: ibeacon, ibeacon-android, android-ibeacon, beacon

First of all, i am trying to find out how the smart wallets works. I am trying to figure out how its works. Basically i need below features :

1.) If someone put out ibeacon from wallet user get notify.

2.) If i tap on wallet user can get call on its mobile application.

As from research i found out this amazing smart wallet [mywalli](http://www.mywalli.com/) and its seems that my requirements are matching very nearly to it. So, i want suggestions that which ibeacon i can use for this as it cover all features as i mentioned above. Your any suggestion are very valuable for me as i am very new in thin ibeacon filed.

Comment: Some manufacturers make credit card form factor beacons.  The card beacon here is an example: http://www.minewtech.com/

Comment: Thanks for sharing. Can you also share any idea about, if there is any hardware which i can use to detect that if someone take out credit card/debit card from wallet? @davidgyoung